# is a closed and bounded set in $\mathbb{C}^n$ under the metric induced by the standard inner product, compact?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I really do ask a question in this post, not saying that i know something.

I want to clarify what i think, which may be trivial to you readers, but which I'm not really sure.

I know the Heine-Borel theorem holds in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but i'm not sure about $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Let $<-,->$ be the standard inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$ be equipped with the topology induced by this inner product.

Define $f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=(Re(x_1),Im(x_1),\cdots,Re(x_n),Im(x_n))$, $\forall x\in\mathbb{C}^n$.

Then $f:\mathbb{C}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ is a homeomorphism.(I have not proven, but i guess so)

More over, $\sqrt{<a,a>}=d(f(a),f(a))$ where $d$ is the standard metric on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Hence, every bounded and closed subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ is compact.

Is my argument correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is a result that says that in a finite-dimensional metric space (wich is the case of $\Bbb{C}^n$), a set is compact if and only if it's closed and bounded.

Comment: Thank you very much. Which category of mathematics could i study this kind of theorems? (That is, results about both topology and linear algebra) I have never learned the theorem you stated and such as "every norm on a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ induce the same topology" in undergraduate course.. fyi, i'm a junior

Comment: This result is part of analysis in abstract metric spaces. Here's a proof of the theorem in page 5: http://www.oswego.edu/Documents/wac/Deans'%20Awards,%202012/math.pdf

Comment: You don't need any notion of dimension for this to work. The general version of the theorem says that any totally bounded complete metric space is compact.

Comment: @user2345215 Yes, but this argument is valid too.